# Shift Rule for Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm trying to show the shift rule for sequences applies for sequences that tend to infinity i.e. $(a_{n}) \rightarrow \infty \Leftrightarrow (a_{N+n}) \rightarrow \infty$

Proof Attempt:

Let $C > 0$. If $(a_{n}) \rightarrow \infty$ then there exists $N_{1}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{n} > C$ for $n > N_{1}$. Observing that $n+N > N_{1}$ we have that $a_{N+n} > C$. Hence $(a_{N+n}) \rightarrow \infty$.

Conversely, suppose $(a_{N+n}) \rightarrow \infty$. Then there exists $N_{2}$ such that $a_{N+n} > C$ for $n > N_{2}$. When $n > N+N_{2}$, then $n - N > N_{2}$, so $ (a_{n}) = a_{N+(n-N)} > C$. Therefore $(a_{n}) \rightarrow \infty$.

Is this proof okay?

Comment: Yep, seems alright.